# Wrong kernel Ubuntu 19.10 with kernel 4.10

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel, versions

I have a system that is about 10 years old with 5 disks. This has slowly been build with boot been moved around as new disks came in. The oldest boot I find is about 9.10. At the moment I boot from sdd6.I have run all updates and upgrades and it works nicely. Today I tried to update : sudo apt-get install linux-generic (suggested in another string) which comes back with nothing to do.

It seems like all utdates are done to sdd6 except the kernel which ends up somewhere else.
How can I solve this issue?

Pål

Comment: Sorry I'm confused by your post, you mention both 9.10 & 19.10, kernel 4.10 (which isn't used by either 9.10 or 19.10), so I'm confused on what you're actually running.  Also what is your architecture (esp. if not amd64/x86_64)

Comment: The 9.10 is an old rest from early days  of the system. I also have found 12.10.Linux uname -a gives Linux Kontor 4.10.0-13-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 9 20:28:34 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note only *standard* support release of Ubuntu are on-topic, any like 9.10 (2009-October) or 12.10 (2012-October) which had only 15 months of supported life, are now years past EOL/*end-of-life* thus off-topic here. For flavors you need to be using 18.04 LTS (LTS=*long-term-support*) or 19.10, though for main Ubuntu & Kylin are still supported for 16.04 LTS.  The *year.month* format makes knowing the age & life of a release very easy; 3 (flavor) or 5 (main) years for LTS, now only 9 months for non-LTS.

Comment: Kernel 4.10 has been *end-of-life* for a long time for example, and thus hasn't had patches for years, and if you're using it, it should not be used on-line unless you've been back-porting patches yourself from supported kernels. Some kernels have longer supported lives (e.g 4.4 is still supported in Ubuntu until next April), but 4.10 wasn't an LTS kernel for Ubuntu patches.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion:

Comment: This are the disks at the moment:sda 1,2,5,6 sdb 1,2,5,6, sdc 1,2,5,6 sdd 1,2,5,6

Comment: This is the grub setup: Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-13-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-13-generic

Comment: Kernels are placed in `/boot/` , so you control it through your file system table entry (`/etc/fstab`) however if you don't provide an entry for /boot/, it'll of course be placed on whichever disk has been assigned to `/`.  I still don't know what you're asking; and could only guess (which isn't usually helpful).

Comment: Thank you for good response. I'll try to be more exact: Why do my system boot with kernel 14.10 even though I have updated/upgraded the kernel all the way? And how do I get kernel and Ubuntu version back in sync?

Comment: I can only guess, but it's possible that you have shadowed directories (ie. issues with your fstab have caused mounts to overshadow installed data); this is somewhat easy on old systems with many drives & partitions..  I would check your grub.cfg; changes made may be written to one drive which is **not** the drive the MBR on your system your BIOS config uses to boot the system (ie. this requires your to move MBR to another drive **or** change bios to use the drive 19.10's is installed on), but I'm only guessing